# Get BSSID (access point MAC address) from C++

Tags: c++, bssid

I'm looking for a C++ method to get the BSSID (access point MAC address) on Windows platform. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetavailablenetworklist)

Comment: @JerryCoffin, This doesn't provide the mac address isn't it,  Just the BSSID count

Comment: Sorry, I posted that kind of prematurely. Once you've found the network you care about, you can call [WlanGetNetworkBssList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetnetworkbsslist) to get the actual BSSIDs for that network (thouhgh you can also skip WlanGetAvailableNetworkList and enumerate *all* available BSSIDs).